# Auto resizing header with changes in window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I currently have some code for a website I am creating for myself.  I am working on making the website adjust to changes in the browser window size.  I can not seem to be able to change my header height according to the browser window size.  For my pictures it works very easy in css:

```
        #logoArea
        {
            width: 15.625%;
            height: auto;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10%;
        }
```

but when I use the same code for my header it does not work:

```
        #header
        {
            background-color: black;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
```

The height of header does not appear all together and a height of 0px is given when I inspected the element.

I tried using .resize() in jQuery as follows:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    AdjustHeader();
                });
            });
            function AdjustHeader(){
                if (jQuery(window).width() = 1600) {
                    jQuery("#header").height(200);
                } 
                else
                {
                    jQuery("#header").height(150);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

This was merely to test out whether I could change the header size using jQuery.  I know you can do it using jQuery.

**Question** If someone could help me out and tell me how to make the header size adjust with changes in browser window size that would be great.  Whether it be in css or jQuery.

Comment: can you create a fiddle link with your code?

Comment: instead of jQuery("#header").height(150); try something like jQuery("#header").css('height','150px');

Comment: is that the whole jQuery code you're using you provided?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I want the header to adjust according to image size

Comment: link to the current state of the website: http://eden.rutgers.edu/~jt533/Webpage.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use media query for this.. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A74Ef/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
    #header {
        height:200px;
    }
}
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 940px) {
    #header {
        height:150px;
    }

}
```

Updated **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A74Ef/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
#header {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;       
    -webkit-transition: .2s height linear;
    -moz-transition: .2s height linear;
    -o-transition: .2s height linear;
    transition: .2s height linear;
}
```

Comment: I like this and I have thoughout about using it but then you get blockwise transitions.  Currently the images adjust continuously with the browser window size.  I would like the header to do the same; adjust with the window browser size and along with the images.

Comment: updated my code with animation.. you can try something else too :)

Answer (score 0):

use media queries and set the desired styles for each breakpoints.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    ...  
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add window re-size listener in jquery. This event will call each time window re-sized. Take a look

```
                   $(window).resize(function(e) {
                             var old_width = e.old.width;
                             var old_height = e.old.height;
                             var new_width = $(this).width();
                             var new_height = $(this).height();
                          // your stuff here 

                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your header is showing up with `height` 0 in the inspector, all of its children are likely floated.

In any case, if you want to decrease the height of your header, you probably want to go to the source and decrease the height of its children.  You would do this as sarbbottam suggested, using media queries.

If you want to know more about media queries, and all you can do with them, you might want to check out [this article](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) on CSS-Tricks.